# Error updating JScript IntelliSense with Google Apis hosted jQuery

Tags: jquery, visual-studio

I reference jQuery in my application via: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js.

This generates an error with vs.net: "Error updating JScript IntelliSense: c:...jquery.min-fds90[1]..js: Object doesn't support this property or method @18:9345.

Other than putting a local copy of the javascript file on my dev box, is there a way to fix this?

Btw, this occurs with VS.Net 2008 SP1 with this hotfix: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx

Comment: This is a real bugger!  I am amazed that it is not reported more wide spread.  Other than using the non-min version, anyone have another solution or is Microsoft or jQuery working on a fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this question:

Basically, add the following to above your jQuery include:

```
<% /* %><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js"></script><% */ %>
```

Via: http://biasecurities.com/blog/2009/get-jquery-intellisense-in-vs-net-when-using-a-cdn/

Comment: I use this solution but instead of wrapping in /* and */ I use if (false) { }, which does the same thing but ReSharper doesn't complain about it. So, I use `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` and `<% if (false) { %><script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script><% } %>`. It works fine despite the minor version mismatch.

Comment: When I try adding either `<% /* %>` or Chris' version `<% if (false) { %>`, I get syntax errors on the first version and the error `'If' must end with a matching 'End If'.` on the second version. Yes, the end tags are there, exactly as written above. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the vsdoc file on the jQuery site has a slightly incorrect filename which confuses VS.

See here:
http://patrickyong.net/2009/05/08/error-updating-jscript-intellisense-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-21391/

Comment: Interesting... It still seems like a bug with vs.net or an issue with the collaboration between jQuery & MS.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem.
This problem only occurs when you use minified version of jQuery.

You can use uncompressed version in development.

Answer (score 0):

I found Rick Strahl's write up to be a really nice start to jQuery including his notes on setup for intellesense and visual studio

[You can find his here.](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/jQuery/default.aspx)